# A difficulty in understanding that $A_4$ has no subgroup of order 6.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Prove that A4 has no subgroups of order 6. (prove by contradiction broken up into 3 cases which each lead to a different kind of contradiction) An outline is given below:

1) Show that the converse of Lagrange's Theorem is false: That is, show that if k divides the order of G, G may not have a subroup of order k. In fact, A4 which has 12 elements does not have any of order 6.

The 12 elements of A4 are: 3-Cycles: (123), (132), (124), (142), (134), (143), (234), (243) Four other permutations which aren’t 3-cycles: (1), (12), (34), (13),(24), (14), (23)

Suppose A4 had a subgroup H of order 6. Then H must contain at least one 3-cycle. (Why?) If H contains a 3-cycle, then it must also contain the inverse of that 3-cycle, so the number of 3-cycles in H must be even— therefore 2, 4, or 6. If H contains six 3-cycles, then we have a contradiction (what is it?). If H contains just two 3-cycles, then H must contain all four of the non-3-cycle permutations, but those four permutations form a subgroup, and 4 does not divide 6, which is a contradiction (show this!) Therefore H contains four 3-cycles—call them a, $a^{−1}$ , b, and $b^{−1}$ . H must also contain ab, $ab^{−1}$ , and (1)—which adds up to seven elements unless two of these elements are the same. Show that’s not the case.

1-I have a difficulty in finding the contradiction in the case when H contains six 3-cycles, could anyone explain for me that contradiction?

2-Also I have a question in that sentence "Therefore H contains four 3-cycles—call them a, $a^{−1}$ , b, and $b^{−1}$ . H must also contain ab, $ab^{−1}$ , and (1)—which adds up to seven elements unless two of these elements are the same. Show that’s not the case." why $a^{-1}b$ & $ba^{-1}$ must not also be in H, could anyone clarify this for me please?Also How can I show that this is not the case?

Many thanks!

Comment: "H must contain at least one 3-cycle. (Why?)".  Not sure if this is you asking or some other author, but just in case, this is a consequence of [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), which states that if $p$ divides the order of $G$, then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.  So if $|H| = 6$, then it must have an element of order $3$, and you can show that any permutation of prime-order $p$ is necessarily a $p$-cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, a group has to contain an identity element, which is not a 3-cycle.

For the second, it's not necessary to find $a^{-1}b$ and $ba^{-1}$ -- it's enough to show that $ab$ and $ab^{-1}$ are too many. We're looking for a contradiction. To show that it's not a contradiction, what would it mean if $ab=ab^{-1}$, or $ab=1$?

Comment: it will mean that b is its own inverse or a is the inverse of b ...... then what is the contradiction in this?